# jQuery Won't Run On IE nor does normal JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, animation, internet-explorer-11

After creating a snippet of code using jQuery, making sure it works on chrome, I tested it out on IE and I realised that none of the jQuery code is running in it. I tried to fix this issue by changing all the jQuery to Pure JS. And still, I get no results. Is anyone here can help me understand why IE is so out of the loop and how I can fix this issue. It's for a client and they are using IE.

So the code is:

```
let Section5Run = true;
const myServices = $('.service-link');

function ServiceSlideIn(services, index = 0) {
if (services.length -1 < index) { return; }
    $(services[index]).css('transform', 'translateX(0%)');
    console.log("Section 5 occurance " + index);
    setTimeout(ServiceSlideIn, 500 , services, ++index);
}

//On Load Page
$(document).ready(function() {

    //When Window Is Scrolled
    $(window).scroll( function(){
        const MSOFFSET = $('.service-link')[0].clientHeight/2;

        var bottom_of_object = $('#section-5-box').offset().top + MSOFFSET;
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object && Section5Run ){
            Section5Run = false;
            ServiceSlideIn(myServices);

        }

    });
});
```

Then it was converted to this:

```
function ServiceSlideIn(services, index = 0) {
if (services.length -1 < index) { return; }
    services[index].style.transform = "translateX(0%)";
    console.log("Section 5 occurance " + index);
    setTimeout(ServiceSlideIn, 500 , services, ++index);
}

var cond = true;

document.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    var wind = window.scrollY;
    var sec_5 = document.getElementById("section-5-box");
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("service-link");
    var sec_off = offset(sec_5).top;
    console.log("rest");
    if (wind + (sec_5.clientHeight * 1.5) > sec_off && cond){
        console.log("Clients's top: " + sec_off);
        console.log("Client's Height is " + sec_5.clientHeight);
        console.log("Window's height: " + (wind + sec_5.clientHeight/3));
        console.log("items Length " + items.length);
        ServiceSlideIn(items);
        cond= false;
    }

});

function offset(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
    scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
    scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    return { top: rect.top + scrollTop, left: rect.left + scrollLeft }
}
```

Pretty basic slide animation done here.

Please do check the website for yourself [cubeangle.com](http://cubeangle.com/) under Our Services the boxes will slide in right to left.

Thank you all.

Comment: It is working in ie11. Please check if by any chance javascript is disabled in your copy of ie

Comment: Wait, what? it does not appear to be working on mine. Also JS is enabled.

Comment: Works on IE10. Are certain IE clients being deceptive because of cached JS? I experience that pain all the time.

Comment: While you guys are at it can you please also check if the card's flip is working? I am still baffled about all this.

Comment: The tab for more areas? The move when I hover over them but I see no flipping.

Comment: No No There will be three cards below the title/menu and those are the ones should be flipping and are wrote with JQ. So I want to make sure that JQ runs too.